# AngularJs: Relative path not redirecting with $location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with angularjs url redirect. Using $location.path() to load the url seems working perfectly with url pattern likes $location.path('/admin'). But when i tried to load $location.path('/admin/home') it didn't work. If i tried with $location.path('home'), the html template is loaded.
Below is my code.

```
  $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            templateUrl: 'Admin/admin.html',
            controller: 'adminController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('admin.home', {
            url: '/admin/home',
            templateUrl: 'Admin/admin.home.html'
            controller: 'adminHomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
```

Controller script

```
authorizeUser(function(result){
     if(result === true) {
         $location.path('/admin/home');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using nested state, don't use `$location.path` here. Instead, inject `$state` and use `$state.go` with the state name as below.

```
authorizeUser(function(result){
     if(result === true) {
         $state.go('admin.home');
     }
}
```

**Note**: As this (`admin.home`) is a nested state of `admin` state, you should have another `ui-view` inside the template `Admin/admin.html` of admin state.

Comment: Thanks a lot man @aruna. You just saved my day. It works like a charm. I just forgot to put ui-view inside the template.

Comment: @CodeRedz Great and can you accept the answer then :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. $state.go() by state id**

```
$state.go('admin.home');
```

**2. $location.path() with url path.**

In my experience, "**$location.path()**" function has a very slight delay to call.

so, you have to use with **$timeout service**.

```
authorizeUser(function(result){
     if(result === true) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $location.path('/admin/home');
        }, 300);
     }
}
```